# msdeploy corrupts connection string passwords

Tags: asp.net, web-config, msdeploy

I have a web application that I am deploying with msdeploy, but at the moment we have an annoying post deployment step - we need to go and patch the passwords in the connectionStrings section.

The password, as entered in IIS manager, is "ABCD%ABCD"
However, after msdeploy has finished its work, the password part of the string has become: ABCDÂ«CD

Clearly, msdeploy is getting confused by the `%` sequence in the password.

If I enter a password with " in it, IIS manager inserts `&quot;`

Now '%' is not one of the characters with a predefined xml entity definition, so, how am I to enter this password so that msdeploy won't corrupt it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the percent character is used to identify environment variables, try using double percent to 'escape' the percent.

e.g. "ABCD%%ABCD"